# Lucky Wheel but i need to limit the number of spin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jscript

As the topic says, I am doing a Wheel of Fortune / Lucky Wheel but I would like to limit the number of spins the guest can make. I am doing a little form at first for the player to enter his username and choose the number of spins.

First Form :

```html
<form action="functions/check_step.php" method="post" class="bg-light p-5">
  <div class="text-center mb-4 mt-n4">
    <h1 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Spin The Wheel</h1>
    <h6 class="text-uppercase"><span class="iconify mr-1 mt-n1 ml-n2" data-icon="simple-icons:onlyfans" data-width="24" data-height="24" style="color: lightblue; padding-top:-10px;"></span>onlyfans.com/melibabies</h6>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="text-center my-4">
    <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Step 1 : CHOOSE YOUR PACKAGE</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input type="text" id="frm1_name" class="form-control" />
    <label class="form-label" for="frm1_name">Your Username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-4">
    <select class="select" name="frm1_nbspin">
      <option value="1">1 Spin</option>
      <option value="2">2 Spins</option>
      <option value="3">3 Spins</option>
    </select>
    <label class="form-label select-label">Choose your Package</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" name="frm1_submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">START</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is the check_step.php file where i take the frm1_nbspin and send it in my js where my js function for limit spins is.

```
<?php 
    include_once "secureStrings.php" ;
    
    session_start();
    
    // CHECK STEP #1
    if (isset($_POST["frm1_submit"])){
        $_SESSION['step1'] == 1; //OPEN SESSION VAR FOR STEP#1
        $frm1_name = sanitizeString($_POST['frm1_name']); //SAVE & SANITIZE USERNAME
        $frm1_nbspin = (int)$_POST['frm1_nbspin']; //SAVE NUMBER OF SPINS AND MAKE SURE IT'S AN INT
    }
    
    // CHECK STEP #2
    if (isset($_POST["frm2_submit"])){
        $_SESSION['step2'] == 1;
    }
    
    // CHECK STEP #3
    if (isset($_POST["frm3_submit"])){
        $_SESSION['step3'] == 1;
        
     }
    
    if ($_SESSION['step1'] != 1) {
        # alert error and return to first step
    }
    
    if ($_SESSION['step2'] != 1) {
        # alert error and return to first step
    }
    
    if ($_SESSION['step3'] != 1) {
        # alert error and return to first step
    }
    
    
    ?>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var frm1_nbspin = <?php echo json_encode($frm1_nbspin) ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/limitspins.js"></script>
```

Here is my New limitspins.js (i created with the comment with code snippet but i really don't know if i did it good ..) And I would like that this function actually limit the spins to 3 if in the first form the guest choose the 3 spins in the select , limit to 2 if he chose the 2 spins , limit to 1 if he chose 1 spin ... For now i just think the code snippet someone gave me can limit only to 3 spins .. but i need it to change depending on the select in the first form.

```js
function limitspin(){
    if (frm1_nbspin > 3) {
        return; 
    }
    frm1_nbspin++
}
```

Here is the Jscript for the wheel and here is my HTML page for the wheel (I don't include the CSS but if it's required let me know I will post/add it.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var x = 1024; //min value
  var y = 9999; // max value

  var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;

  document.getElementById('box').style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";

  var element = document.getElementById('mainbox');
  element.classList.remove('animate');

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add('animate');
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 second
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(60, 60, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 245, 230, 1) 52%, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.mainbox:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('../img/arrow-wheel.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 32px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 5s;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.span1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 92%, 100% 50%, 0 8%);
  background-color: #fffb00;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

.span2 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 92%, 0 50%, 100% 8%);
  background-color: #ff4fa1;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.span3 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 8% 100%, 92% 100%);
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.span4 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 92% 0, 8% 0);
  background-color: #22ff00;
  top: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.box1 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-270deg);
}

.box1 .span1 b,
.box2 .span1 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(185deg);
}

.box2 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.box1 .span4 b,
.box2 .span4 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-85deg);
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

span b {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #001aff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin:active {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainbox.animate:after {
  animation: animateArrow 0.7s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animateArrow {
  50% {
    right: -40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
    <div id="box" class="box">
      <div class="box1">
        <span class="span1"><b>Option1</b></span>
        <span class="span2"><b>Option2</b></span>
        <span class="span3"><b>Option3</b></span>
        <span class="span4"><b>Option4</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <span class="span1"><b>Option5</b></span>
        <span class="span2"><b>Option6</b></span>
        <span class="span3"><b>Option7</b></span>
        <span class="span4"><b>Option8</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="spin" onclick="myfunction()">SPIN</button>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am not really good with javascript I am really a beginner with it ...

Comment: Don't use a snippet if there's nothing to execute or that doesn't add anything useful to the question when executed. All those snippets should be normal code blocks or re-written into _one_ snippet that actually does something useful.

Comment: Basic idea `var spins = 0; function myfunction(){  if (spins > 4) { return; } spins++`

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And why is this tagged with `jscript`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear how the values from the first form get to the second page. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: PS: I know that i will be passing the form frm1_nbspin in a session to keep the value to the script where i will limit the nb of spins...

Comment: I have edited and converted your HTML/JS to Snippet. Yes, you can add CSS, it may help.

Comment: And , i will be editing the wheel to have 15 "panel" / "options" on it if it changes anything .. idk. But anyway i will try doing something with the little code snippet from epascarello ...

Comment: @Charles I didn't snub you, I could have downvoted or voted to close the post. Instead I tried to empower you and offer you resources so that you could provide more details to the post and get the help you need. As it is now, many will not be able to help you as the post is lacking some details that only you can provide.

Comment: @Twisty ... sorry but i didn't find that your comment was constructive .. maybe i took it badly .. sorry bout that. I will try to add more code but it will have a bunch of codes and it's hard to understand when there is 10 different codes ... That's why i tried to limit to the things i thought it was needed to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
var spinCount = 0;

function myfunction() {
  if (spinCount > 3) {
    alert("No more Spins");
    return false;
  }
  var x = 1024; //min value
  var y = 9999; // max value

  var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;

  document.getElementById('box').style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";

  var element = document.getElementById('mainbox');
  element.classList.remove('animate');

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add('animate');
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 second
  spinCount++;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body {
  font-family: Open Sans;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(60, 60, 242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 0%, rgba(98, 245, 230, 1) 52%, rgba(60, 60, 242, 1) 100%);
  background-size: cover;
}

.mainbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.mainbox:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('../img/arrow-wheel.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 32px;
  right: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all ease 5s;
}

span {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.span1 {
  clip-path: polygon(0 92%, 100% 50%, 0 8%);
  background-color: #fffb00;
  top: 120px;
  left: 0;
}

.span2 {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 92%, 0 50%, 100% 8%);
  background-color: #ff4fa1;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
}

.span3 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 8% 100%, 92% 100%);
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.span4 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 100%, 92% 0, 8% 0);
  background-color: #22ff00;
  top: 0;
  left: 120px;
}

.box1 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-270deg);
}

.box1 .span1 b,
.box2 .span1 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(185deg);
}

.box2 .span3 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.box1 .span4 b,
.box2 .span4 b {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-85deg);
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

span b {
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  background-color: #001aff;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.spin:active {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.mainbox.animate:after {
  animation: animateArrow 0.7s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes animateArrow {
  50% {
    right: -40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mainbox" class="mainbox">
    <div id="box" class="box">
      <div class="box1">
        <span class="span1"><b>Option1</b></span>
        <span class="span2"><b>Option2</b></span>
        <span class="span3"><b>Option3</b></span>
        <span class="span4"><b>Option4</b></span>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <span class="span1"><b>Option5</b></span>
        <span class="span2"><b>Option6</b></span>
        <span class="span3"><b>Option7</b></span>
        <span class="span4"><b>Option8</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="spin" onclick="myfunction()">SPIN</button>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This creates a Global Variable, so regardless of how many times the User clicks to Spin, it will track the number of clicks. I set `3` for now in this example. Your code will have a variable number from the first page.

**Update**

Consider the following in your `check_step.php` file:

```
<?php 
include_once "secureStrings.php" ;

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['step'])){
  $_SESSION['step'] = 0;
}

switch($_SESSION['step']){
  case 1:
    $_SESSION['spins'] = (int)$_POST['frm1_nbspin'];
    $dest = "spin-step2.php";
    break;
  case 2:
    $dest = "spin-step3.php";
    break;
  case 3:
    $dest = "spin.html";
    break;
  default:
    $_SESSION["error"] = "AN ERROR HAS OCCURED!\r\nPLEASE TRY AGAIN";
    $dest = "spin-step1.php";
    break;
}

header("location: ../" . $dest);
exit();
?>
```

You can see here that this collects the details from the form and places them in the Session. In the other pages, we can now collect that detail from the session when the page loads.

See More:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thanks man !!! but with this code , will the spins will be limited depending on what the person chose in the first form ? because what i would need is that if the person chose from the select box (in first form) 1 spin it's limited to 1 spin , if chose 2 spins ; limited to 2 spins and 3 for 3 spins ..

edit: and is there something new in the css ?

Comment: @Charles so read the value from the select and use that in the if statement.

Comment: @Charles not with this exact code. There is no way for me to simulate the PHP or Session data in this example. Your code will be a little different as it may be generated by PHP. So your IF statement might be something like `if (spinCount > <?php echo $frm1_nbspin; ?>) {`

Comment: @Twisty Look at my answer i just post , would it be good like that ? i think it's almost the same has you just commented ..

Answer (score 0):

@Twisty

Is this good ?

check_step.php

```
<?php 
include_once "secureStrings.php" ;

session_start();

// CHECK STEP #1
if (isset($_POST["frm1_submit"])){
    $_SESSION['step1'] == 1; //OPEN SESSION VAR FOR STEP#1
    $frm1_name = sanitizeString($_POST['frm1_name']); //SAVE & SANITIZE USERNAME
    $frm1_nbspin = (int)$_POST['frm1_nbspin']; //SAVE NUMBER OF SPINS AND MAKE SURE IT'S AN INT
}

// CHECK STEP #2
if (isset($_POST["frm2_submit"])){
    $_SESSION['step2'] == 1;
}

// CHECK STEP #3
if (isset($_POST["frm3_submit"])){
    $_SESSION['step3'] == 1;
    
 }

if ($_SESSION['step1'] != 1) {
    # alert error and return to first step
}

if ($_SESSION['step2'] != 1) {
    # alert error and return to first step
}

if ($_SESSION['step3'] != 1) {
    # alert error and return to first step
}


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm1_nbspin = <?php echo json_encode($frm1_nbspin) ?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/wheel.js"></script>
```

and in my wheel.js

```js
var spinCount = 0;

function myfunction() {
  if (spinCount > frm1_nbspin) {
    alert("No more Spins");
    return false;
  }
  var x = 1024; //min value
  var y = 9999; // max value

  var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * (x - y)) + y;

  document.getElementById('box').style.transform = "rotate(" + deg + "deg)";

  var element = document.getElementById('mainbox');
  element.classList.remove('animate');

  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add('animate');
  }, 5000); //5000 = 5 second
  spinCount++;
}
```

I used your code but i pass my variable where i retrieve the nb of spins selected from the first form to the wheel.js and have the spinCount > frm1_nbspin since i want the spinCount to be limited with the choice of the select box from form1 ?

Comment: It is using some code methods that are considered bad practice, yet it looks like it would work as expected. This is assuming that all JavaScript is in in the same page as the PHP.

Comment: Oh so i need to have my check_step.php and wheel.js in the same page ? it would be a .php or a .js ? I am really confuse right now .. lol im so trash with javascript xD

Comment: No, in you  PHP, you have a Script block and then call the JS library, that is fine. Just want to ensure that `myfunction()` is also inside the same PHP Page. I suspect that it is already.

Comment: ohh Okok , fine i will try to make all this work :) thanks a lot man !!! <3

Comment: @Twisty ; I just tried all the codes everything is fine until im at the wheel page and i cant even do 1 spin ... :S i really dont know what is wrong ... i will upload all the scripts on my website and share the url to you if you could look at it man it would be awesome.

here is the link www.creativewebconcept.ca/dl/spinwheel.rar

Comment: @Twisty ? could you check or ?

Comment: looking at it but I do have other things going on.

Comment: @Twisty ah okok no worry bro take your time , just comment here or pm me if you find anything to make it works :) thanks a lot !

Comment: There are an impressive number of things that need to be addressed, many more than I can go into at this time. The primary issue is that when you post the Form data to `check_step.php`, this page adds some data to the session, yet does not proceed with anything. I was expecting a redirection or more content to be shown, yet this is not the case. So there is no relationship between the Spinner and the Data.

Comment: @Twisty then lmk if you have time i will try to fix it by myself for now ! Thanks anyway man ;)

EDIT: i just checked what your talking bout in check_step.php and yeah ther's a redirect x)
                  .
    $_SESSION['step1'] = 1; //OPEN SESSION VAR FOR STEP#1
    extract($_POST);
    $frm1_name = sanitizeString($_POST['frm1_name']); //SAVE & SANITIZE USERNAME
    $frm1_nbspin = (int)$_POST['frm1_nbspin']; //SAVE NUMBER OF SPINS AND MAKE SURE IT'S AN INT
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'window.location.replace("../spin-step2.php");';
    echo '</script>';
}

Comment: @Twisty Bro if you want just add me on discord and we can discuss that more properly when you and I got free time x) cuz i hate stackoverflow msg and post and comments layout it's so horrible XD my discord is : LocalKush#1391   just add me and dm me ;) I would really appreciate that and I thank you so much for the time your putting for helping me tho <3

Comment: Update my answer. Take a look.

Comment: @Twisty ; Ok i just updated with the code you posted but now i cant get past step1 lol ... Still i dont know why i would have changed the code with yours .. it's maybe more properly done for the redirection but that's it x) ? I just woke up so im a bit confuse imma check it again later if I can understand better but hmm xD

Comment: Should I have other things to edit to make this works ? or It's supose to work with just the modifications you made ? xd

Comment: @Twisty ; I'm totally more confuse than before with your new answer loll ... i'm tryna figure out why your new answer is supose to fix things ... ok you used a switch instead of my if statements it's better i understand that , you have the redirect setted better but it's using a Header Location which the check_step.php isn't an include it's called with a form action so i dont think a header location would work ? (it's not supose to be at first before any other code .. ? it's a Header so .. )

Comment: I'm starting to think that I am just fking dumb XD

Comment: @Twisty ; you should have comment your code so i could understand a bit better maybe idk ? i'm still tryna figure out why it's not working even with your update answer's code...